# Python Django: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

I'm trying to deploy my Django application to the web, but I get the following error:

> You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT
>   setting to a filesystem path

However, I did in my **production.py**:

```
from django.conf import settings

DEBUG = False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True
DATABASES = settings.DATABASES

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')

# Update database configuration with $DATABASE_URL.
import dj_database_url
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
)

# Simplified static file serving.
# https://warehouse.python.org/project/whitenoise/

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

What is the `production.py` file? How do you import your settings?

Depending on how you got this error (serving django through a wsgi server or on the command line), check for `manage.py` or `wsgi.py` to see what is the name of the default settings file.

If you want to manuallly set the settings to use, use something like this:

```
./manage.py --settings=production
```

Where `production` is any python module.

Moreover, your settings file should not import anything django related. If you want to split your settings for different environments, use something like this.

A file `settings/base.py`

```
# All settings common to all environments
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')
```

Files like `settings/local.py`, `settings/production.py`…

```
# Production settings
from settings.base import *
DEBUG = False
DATABASES = …
```

Answer (score 42):

If you are using `Django 2.2` or greater, your settings file already has a line similar to this:

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Therefore you can easily set static like so:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the `STATIC_ROOT` setting to the directory from which you’d like to serve static files, for example:

`STATIC_ROOT = "/var/www/example.com/static/"`

The settings you are using are for development. Check the Django docs for more information [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/)

Comment: it's work. if you are deploy web hosting with cpanel python app: STATIC_ROOT = "/home/user/sub.domain.com/static/" and then type: ./manage.py migrate ./manage.py collectstatic, restart django

Comment: If you use STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static') and run "python manage.py collectstatic", a folder named 'static" will be created at the same location where manage.py is, if the folder does not exits.
If you use STATIC_ROOT = "/tmp/static/", a folder will be created in the same manner. This works on Windows as well at the same drive, i. e. "C:\".

Answer (score 2):

Django settings for static assets can be a bit difficult to configure and debug. However, if you just add the following settings to your settings.py, everything should work exactly as expected:

> goto "settings.py" add following code

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

See a full version of our example settings.py [on GitHub](https://github.com/heroku/python-getting-started/blob/master/gettingstarted/settings.py).

> now create static folder in root directory, and a random file inside
> it.

Django won’t automatically create the target directory (STATIC_ROOT) that collectstatic uses, if it isn’t available. You may need to create this directory in your codebase, so it will be available when collectstatic is run. Git does not support empty file directories, so you will have to create a file inside that directory as well.

for more refer: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets

Answer (score 0):

This is the most basic and easy solution, i faced the same error while installing `datta admin`.
This solved my problem. Add this code in your `settings.py` file in your project core directory.

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / STATIC_URL
```